# ExpectSaga put assertion failes with multiple put effects

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, redux-saga-test-plan

The saga has multiple puts.

```
export function* changeItemsSaga(action) {
    const prerequisite1 = yield select(prerequisite1Selector);

    // some processing

    yield put(actions.myAction1(payload1));

    // some more processing

    const prerequisite2 = yield select(prerequisite2Selector);

    // some more processing

    yield put(actions.myAction2(payload2));
}
```

How do I write my put expectations when the saga is returning multiple effects?

```
it('should update items', () =>
    expectSaga(sagas.changeItemsSaga, action)
        .provide([
            [select(prerequisite1), {}],
            [select(prerequisite2), {}],
        ])
        .put([actions.myAction1(payload1), actions.myAction2(payload2)])
        .run());
```

ExpectSaga unit test returns the following error:

```
Saga test error:
put expectation unmet:

Expected
--------
{ channel: null,
  action:
   [ { type: 'MY_ACTION_1',
       payload: { myItem1: [Object] } },
     { type: 'MY_ACTION_2',
       payload: { itemCollection: [Object] } } ] }

Actual:
------
1. { channel: null,
  action:
   { type: 'MY_ACTION_1',
     payload:
      { myItem1:
         { index: 0,
           childItem1: [Object],
           childItem2: [Object] } } } }
2. { channel: null,
  action:
   { type: 'MY_ACTION_2',
     payload: { itemCollection: [ [Object] ] } } }
```

This one doesn't work either.

```
it('should update items', () =>
    expectSaga(sagas.changeItemsSaga, action)
        .provide([
            [select(prerequisite1), {}],
            [select(prerequisite2), {}],
        ])
        .put(actions.myAction1(payload1))
        .put(actions.myAction2(payload2))
        .run());
```

It returns this error.

```
Saga test error:
put expectation unmet:

Expected
--------
{ channel: null,
  action:
   { type: 'MY_ACTION_1',
     payload:
      { myItem1:
         { index: 0,
           childItem1: [Object],
           childItem2: [Object] } } } }

Actual:
------
1. { channel: null,
  action:
   { type: 'MY_ACTION_1',
     payload:
      { myItem1:
         { index: 0,
           childItem1: [Object],
           childItem2: [Object] } } } }
2. { channel: null,
  action:
   { type: 'MY_ACTION_2',
     payload: { itemCollection: [ [Object] ] } } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `provide` syntax allows you to test the final effect of the saga instead of bootstrapping all of your state.

Here's an example from  the [redux-saga docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing.html) -

```
test('test only final effect with .provide()', () => {
  /*
  * With the .provide() method from expectSaga
  * you can by pass in all expected values
  * and test only your saga's final effect.
  */
  return expectSaga(callApi, 'url')
    .provide([
      [select(selectFromState), selectedValue],
      [call(myApi, 'url', selectedValue), response]
    ])
    .put(success(response))
    .run();
});
```

By invoking the `actions` call 2x, the test is running in succession, and the `put` in the middle of `sagas.changeItemsSaga` is effectively skipped.

It looks like the function which you might be after is [testSaga](https://github.com/jfairbank/redux-saga-test-plan#unit-testing) which will give you more fine-grained insight into the flow of the effects.